# drop down menu won't go horizontal

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm making my first website with HTML and CSS and it's all gone fine, but now I'm stumped. I made a pretty typical horizontal menu under my header using the inline command in my CSS. Then I decided I wanted drop down elements on my menu, so deleted all my menu css and copied in some new from a tutorial for horizontal drop down menus online. The drop downs work perfectly, but now, for some reason, my menu is vertical! Any ideas how I can make it horizontal again? Hoping it should be relatively easy! Thanks so much.

**Here's my html (in my .html sheet)**

```
<div class="header">

<div class="topimagebox">
<img src="images/header1.jpg" class="topimage"; alt="Nets drying at Folkestone harbour";>
</div> <!--topimagebox-->

  <ul id="Menu">
    <li ><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li ><a href="About.html">About</a>
                                <ul>
                                <li ><a href="Context.html">Context</a></li>
                                <li ><a href="About.html">The Project</a></li>
                                <li ><a href="People.html">People</a></li>
                                </ul>   
                          </li>  
    <li ><a href="News.html">News</a></li>
    <li  ><a href="Publications.html">Publications</a></li>
    <li  ><a href="CaseStudies.html">Case Studies</a></li>
    <li  ><a href="Contactus.html">Contact</a>
                                <ul>
                                <li ><a href="Contactus.html">Contact</a></li>
                                <li ><a href="Getinvolved.html">Get Involved</a></li>
                                </ul>
                           </li>
    <li class="menu" ><a href="Impact.html">Impact</a></li>
    <li class="menu"><a href="Links.html">Links</a></li>
  </ul>


</div> <!--header-->
```

And here's my CSS (in a seperate stylesheet)

```
div.header {
  background-color: white;
  width: 1000px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
ul {
  padding: 0px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin: 0px;
}


li {
  width: 850px;
  margin:0px auto 0px auto;
}

#Menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 1em; }

#Menu li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left; }

#Menu li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 8px;
    background-color: #5e8ce9;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none; }

#Menu li ul {
    display: none; 
    width: 10em; /* Width to help Opera out */
    background-color: #69f;}

#Menu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; }

#Menu li:hover li {
    float: none; }

#Menu li:hover li a {
    background-color: #69f;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #000; }

#Menu li li a:hover {
    background-color: #8db3ff; }
```

I put in my generic ul and li in case that had something to do with it. If anyone can help, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
li {
  width: 850px; //<-- This is your problem.
  margin:0px auto 0px auto; 
}
```

If you remove the width the li-elements will float next to each other, until there isnt anymore room for it to float, then it will break onto a new row.

Comment: Razz, you boss! Thanks so much.

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle showing what Razz recommends. http://jsfiddle.net/gkRM7/ Likewise, you can define your li elements by setting their width to 12.5%, as 8 * 12.5% = 100% so that your menu will properly and completely size to the window.  #Menu li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    width: 12.5%;
    }

Comment: Thanks so much guys. Dumb question, but if I want to change colour when you hover on the links, where should I insert that in the above CSS? Now that I imported rather than starting from scratch I've lost my bearings a bit. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You have a :hover-selector on a link already, but maybe its too far down in your structure.
Try changing your last selector to #Menu li a:hover{...} to get all a-links, not just the ones beneath two li:s

Comment: Oh you guys, that works great! The width thing made me go onto another line - I think because I test-transformed to uppercase, converted my font-weight to bold and added a letter-spacing of 0.2em. I might take all those off though because spaced out is nicer.